# Creating a message in an Inbox by Gmail thread via Gmai API

Tags: gmail-api, google-inbox

Steps to reproduce:

1. Send a message from Inbox
2. Create a 2nd message in that same thread using Gmail API's "insert" method
3. Delete the first message either from the API or from Gmail (but really delete it, not just put it into trash)

Result: the 2nd message seems to get somehow disconnected from the thread and Inbox acts weirdly on it (see [video](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ugieuyce4k3p0d1/screen.mp4?dl=0) if curious -- the weird behaviour itself starts at 2:10).

Bug or feature?

How to avoid it?

Comment: Well, I think it is because of the 1st message that you deleted. The 2nd message exist as a another message that based on the threadId of the 1st message. So if you delete the 1st or original message, its threadId also be deleted. So it will affect  all the message that it based on it.

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't happen if the 2nd message is created using Inbox -- apparently in that case the 2nd message receives the threadId by itself, not just based on the 1st.